# dropdown menu goes under select2

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

What css property or jQuery code can fix this annoying problem?
[image]

Comment: ```z-index``` will fix your problem.

Comment: increase z-index of your dropdown to more than select2's z-index.

Comment: thanks guys that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give z-index value to drop-down. like:

```
    .drop-down-className {
        z-index: 999;
    }
```

Comment: It is not working in mdbootstrap mega menu due to bootstrap-grid.css markups for grid system. I mean `col-**-*` class.